# angular 2 - initial state of the list of checkboxes

Tags: angular, checkbox

I'm new to Angular :) I'm trying to set the initial state of checkboxes.
I have a post and categories, some of them already assigned to that post. When I navigate to the post edit page there's a list of all categories, which I can select / deselect. What I try to achieve is that on init certain checkboxes (categories already assigned to the post) are checked.
Here's what I have:

```
//document-edit.component.html
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   [checked]="checkIfCategoryAssigned(category.documents, document.id)"
                   (change)="onChange(category.id, category.name, $event.target.checked)"> {{category.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

// document-edit.component.ts
checkIfCategoryAssigned(categoryDocuments, documentId) {
    for (let document of categoryDocuments) {
        if (document.id === documentId) {
            console.log('true');
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be working, but the problem is that the function is called on every mouse move! I've read that I should use an Observable but I have no idea how. The Angular docs doesn't cover this particular scenario.

Comment: "function is called on every mouse move" ? can you create plunker

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it.

Comment: I may take time (the app is pretty complex), meanwhile there's the clue I've read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583967/angular2-why-functions-are-called-each-time-i-move-the-mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do default checked whenever the page loads you can create a variable and set the default to true in your component then something like the following should work:

component:

```
public isUser: boolean = true;
public isAdmin: boolean =false;
```

In your htlml:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="roles">Roles</label>
  <div class="col-md-4" >
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="isUser">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="isUser" [(ngModel)]="isUser" #isuser="ngModel">Can Login</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="isAdmin">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="isAdmin" [(ngModel)]="isAdmin" #isadmin="ngModel">Is Admin</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are trying to load based on saved values you can use snapshot data and do something like the following in your component:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.user = this.route.snapshot.data['user'];
        this.isUser = this.user.roles.includes('user');
        this.isAdmin = this.user.roles.includes('admin');
}
```

(I'm using the same HTML file for both of these examples)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. I know how to set initial state. But in this case I have an array of categories, some of them needs to be checked on init, same not. It depends if the categories are assigned to certain post. Post object contains its categories, category object contains posts - it's many-to-many relation selected from the backend. So first I need to loop the categories and check if this document id === category document id. If yes - checkbox should be checked on init.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I end up with this. Seems like a better approach:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {DocumentService} from './document.service';
import {AlertService} from '../alert/alert.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'document-edit',
    templateUrl: './document-edit.component.html',
})

export class DocumentEditComponent implements OnInit {

    public document: any;
    public categories: any;
    public categoriesArray: Array<{id: number, name: string}> = [];

    constructor(
        private documentService: DocumentService,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.documentService.getDocument(+params['id']))
            .subscribe(document => this.document = document);
        this.getCategories();
    }


    /*
     * Push categories already assigned to this document
     * to an array used in updateDocument method
     * and check already assigned categories in the template.
     */
    documentCategories(document: any, categories: any) {
        for (let documentCategory of document.categories) {
            this.categoriesArray.push({id: documentCategory.id, name: documentCategory.name});
        }           
        for (let category of categories) {
            for (let categoryDocument of category.documents) {
                if (categoryDocument.id === document.id) {
                    category.checked = true;
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    onChange(id: number, name: string, isChecked: boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
            if (this.categoriesArray.some(x => x.name === name)) {
                return;
            } else {
                this.categoriesArray.push({id: id, name: name});
            }
        } else {
            let index: number = this.categoriesArray.indexOf(this.categoriesArray.find(x => x.name === name));
            this.categoriesArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
        return this.categoriesArray;
    }

    updateDocument(id: number, title: string, body: any) {
        let document = {id: id, title: title, body: body, categories: this.categoriesArray};
        this.documentService.updateDocument(document).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.alertService.success('Document updated.');
                return true;
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error("Error updating document! " + error);
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        );
    }

    getCategories() {
        this.documentService.getCategories().subscribe(
            data => {this.categories = data},
            err => console.error(err),
            () => this.documentCategories(this.document, this.categories)
        );
    }

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }

}
```

Template:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="document-title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       class="form-control" 
                       id="document-title" 
                       name="document-title" [(ngModel)]="document.title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="document-body">Body</label>
                <simple-tiny
                    name="document-body"
                    elementId="document-body"
                    [(ngModel)]="document.body">
                </simple-tiny>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Categories</label>                           
            <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               [checked]=category.checked
                               (change)="onChange(category.id, category.name, $event.target.checked)"> {{category.name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" 
                    class="btn btn-default" 
                    (click)="updateDocument(document.id, document.title, document.body)">
                    Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```